# Adding a slash after just the first link in an UL

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I want to add a slash after the first link in my UL, but it keeps adding it after every link. I've tried a million different things but I can't seem to figure it out.

My view/html:

```
    <?php foreach ($this->config->item('languages') as $i => $language): ?>

    <li class="language-nav__item"<?php if ($i == 0): ?> <?php elseif ($i == sizeof($this->config->item('languages'))-1): ?><?php endif; ?>>
        <a class="language-nav__link" href="<?php echo base_url() . $language['alias'] . '/' . $pages[$view]->{'url_' . $language['language']}; echo ($view == 'home')? '' : str_replace('/' . $this->uri->segment(1), '', uri_string()); ?>">
            <?php echo $language['name']; ?> 
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

This displays two links/languages.

Then in my CSS:

```
.language-nav a:nth-child(1):before { 
  content: "/";
  color: white;
}
```

This displays a slash after each link. And when I target it like this:

```
.language-nav li:nth-child(1):before { 
  content: "/";
  color: white;
```

}

It adds a slash AFTER the last link instead of the first (so not in the middle where it needs to be)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you were targeting the first child within the `li`'s themselves.

Try the below.

```css
li:first-child a:after {
  content: "/";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
     <a class="language-nav__link" href="#">
         English
     </a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a class="language-nav__link" href="#">
         Spanish
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a class="language-nav__link" href="#">
         Chinese
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This targets the anchor element within the first `li` (ie - `first-child` of the `ul`).

EDIT - alternatively, to get the slash outside of the anchor:

```css
li:first-child:after {
      content: "/";
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="language-nav__link" href="#">
      English
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="language-nav__link" href="#">
      Spanish
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="language-nav__link" href="#">
      Chinese
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So this works like a charm, thank you but how can I target the specific <li> element? Because now it, of course, adds a slash to every first li of the page.

Comment: @magin You can add a class to the parent `ul` you want the style to apply to (ie - `<ul class="yourclass">`) and then target like this: `ul.yourclass li:first-child:after {}`